# Read CSV/Excel file into array

Tags: vba, csv, outlook

I am trying to make a macro which copies emails when I receive them, and saves them  in specific windows folders on a network drive based on the domain name.

The list of domains I have will be large and subject to change by users without coding experience, so I am looking to develop a text, CSV, or excel file that someone can update which lists my company's relationship to them (client, vendor, sub-contractor, etc...) and their name (both of which controls the file path), the domain name (@example.com).

I think I can figure out how to do most of that (a clever combination of nested if and for statements), but I can't figure out how to read the file into an array, and my google-fu has failed me.

I don't think it really helps, but here is the code that I shamelessly copied from the web and am planning to work off of.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items

Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set xNameSpace = Outlook.Application.Session
    Set InboxItems = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Dim FSO
    Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xFilePath As String
    Dim xRegEx
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim SenderAddress As String
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Define SenderAddress as sender's email address or domain
    xFilePath = PathCreator(SenderAddress)

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FolderExists(xFilePath) = False Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (xFilePath)

    End If

    Set xRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    xRegEx.Global = True
    xRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
    xRegEx.Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?"

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set xMailItem = objItem
        xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "")
        xMailItem.SaveAs xFilePath & "\" & xFileName & ".html", olHTML

    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Function PathCreator(SenderAddress)

' [needs to read the file and create the path based on the values]

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADODB to connect to the source file, and read it into a 2-dimensional array. Add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** from **Tools** -> **References...**. For example, if you want to use an Excel file:

```
Dim excelPath As String
excelPath = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx" ' Replace with the path to the Excel file

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & excelPath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
'This assumes the Excel file contains column headers -- HDR=Yes

Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT Relationship, LastName, FirstName, DomainName FROM [Sheet1$]"
'Assumes the relevant worksheet is named Sheet1
'Also assumes the first row of the sheet has the following labels: Relationship, LastName, FirstName, Domain (in no particular order)

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Dim arr As Variant
arr = rs.GetRows 'Puts the data from the recordset into an array
rs.Close 
Set rs = Nothing

Dim row As Variant, column As Variant
For row = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
    For column = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
        Debug.Print arr(column, row)
    Next
Next
```

Using a text file or CSV is just a matter of slightly changing the connection string and the SQL. But I think using an Excel file will force the users to keep the data in columns, where in a CSV users would have to insert field- and row-separators manually; the same for any other text format -- users would have to remember the format's rules and apply them correctly.

---

But I question if an array is the best data structure for you to use; in this case you could use the recordset directly. In order to make sure the file is not held open, you could use a disconnected recordset. (If your intention is to find the appropriate domain name and use that to get other details, then I would suggest you load the data from a recordset into a Scripting.Dictionary.)

Also note that you probably only need to load the data from the file once, unless you expect it to change while the code is running.

I would write something like this

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Function PathCreator(SenderAddress) As String
    If rs Is Nothing Then
        Dim excelPath As String
        excelPath = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx" ' Replace with the path to the Excel file

        Dim connectionString As String
        connectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""" & excelPath & """;" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

        Dim sql As String
        sql = "SELECT Relationship, LastName, FirstName, DomainName FROM [Sheet1$]"

        Set rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        rs.Open sql, connectionString, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

        'Disconnect the recordset
        rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

        'Now the data will still be available as long as the code is running
        'But the connection to the Excel file will be closed
    End If

    'build the path here, using the recordset fields
    PathCreator = rs!Relationship & "_" & rs!LastName & "_" & rs!FirstName & "_" & rs!Domain
End Function
```

---

NB. By the same token, you can add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**; then you can write the code that uses the FileSystemObject as follows:

```
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If Not FSO.FolderExists(xFilePath) Then
    FSO.CreateFolder xFilePath

End If
```

and with a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** libary:

```
Set xRegEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
xRegEx.Global = True
xRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
xRegEx.Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?"

If objItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set xMailItem = objItem
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "")
    xMailItem.SaveAs xFilePath & "\" & xFileName & ".html", olHTML

End If
```